# How to turn off family sharing for an app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Apples new family sharing appears to be turned on when the latest contract agreements are signed.

Is there a way to turn this off for individual apps?

Answer (score 5):

[NB. answer was re situation in 2015 - please check comments, apparently situation has changed since]

No opt-out, family-sharing comes "bundled" with the new contract. Notice the following twists however:

- There was an **additional** prod in iTunes Connect / Agreements, Tax, and Banking, asking you to extent family-sharing backwards to previous sales. If you didn't do that, AppStore will show in app information "Family Sharing: Yes, **for purchases after** *[some_date]*" (where *some_date* is your date of agreeing to the new contract. - this has now been removed since Family Sharing is automatically enabled when you agree to the updated agreement
- IAP (in-app purchases) are not covered by family sharing, so can put your non-family jewels there.

Comment: I think this answer is outdated. There is no family sharing in agreements, tax and banking now.

Comment: @Nas Banov Can you please confirm it? Is it a part of agreement.

Comment: did you get any solution to hide this family sharing option ?